# hang while building spark1.6.1 with cloudera hadoop5.7.0

Tags: apache-spark, build, cloudera-cdh

I've tried build spark1.6.1 source code to binary by using make_distribution.sh

but it seems stop or hang... since terminal is stop like this view and no other messages

[image]

I use shell commend like this,

```
./make-distribution.sh --name spark-1.6.1-bin-cdh5.7.0 -Phadoop-2.6 -Pyarn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

Is this commend right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 1 hour later with above static message... build process starts!

it was just matter of time...